# how to show random images when when click on button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript so don't have that much knowledge of js so I have requirement of generate random images when click on button, images are displaying using php(codeigniter framework) how to show random images on every click like a.jpg should come first sometimes last or b.jpg should come first or last

```
<img src="<?=base_url('assets/game/a.jpg')?>" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="<?=base_url('assets/game/b.jpg')?>" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="<?=base_url('assets/game/c.jpg')?>" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="<?=base_url('assets/game/d.jpg')?>" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="<?=base_url('assets/game/e.jpg')?>" style="width:120px;"><br>

<button class="btn btn-success clk_btn" onclick="myfunction">generate random imgaes</button>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: First of all, your question is tagged as `javascript` but you are using a php framework. So, which one would that be? Second, assign an ID to each image (something like `<img id="Image_1"...` till `"Image_5"`, and in your code use a random number generator that would give results between 1 and 5. Then, use styling to set the element `"show" or `"hide"` depending on the resulting random number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, just replace the div with your images, also you might want to change the numbers based on the amount of pictures.

```js
function random () {
  const randomNr = Math.random()*100;
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  
  elements.forEach((el) => el.style.display = 'none')

  if (randomNr < 34) {
    elements[0].style.display = 'block';
  } else if(randomNr < 64) {
      elements[1].style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      elements[2].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>image1</div>
<div>image2</div>
<div>image3</div>

<button onclick="random()">switch</button>
```

Comment: What a weird construction. Is this to make it more varied?

Answer (score -1):

A possibility is to hide all images by adding a "hidden" attribute and on the click, choose a random one and remove that "hidden" attribute ;)

```js
let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
  images[i].setAttribute('hidden', true);
    


function myfunction()
{
  let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    images[i].setAttribute('hidden', true);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
  images[rand].removeAttribute('hidden');
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350?text=A" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350?text=B" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350?text=C" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350?text=D" style="width:120px;"><br>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350?text=E" style="width:120px;"><br>

<button class="btn btn-success clk_btn" onclick="myfunction()">generate random imgaes</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: If you do `const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');` then you can reuse the images const in the second part

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code.

```js
// Javascript
var images = [
  "<?=base_url('assets/game/a.jpg')?>",
  "<?=base_url('assets/game/b.jpg')?>",
  "<?=base_url('assets/game/c.jpg')?>",
  "<?=base_url('assets/game/d.jpg')?>",
  "<?=base_url('assets/game/e.jpg')?>"
];

document.getElementById("my_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("my_image").src = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)%5]
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<button id="my_button">Generate random image</button>
<br>
<img id="my_image" style="width:120px;"/>
```

Documentation:

- [Math.random() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [Math.floor() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)